# Using Silverlight without knowing about it?

Tags: c++, silverlight, browser, post

I know nothing about Silverlight or any type of scripting, and don't have time to learn about it.  I have a Visual C++ client application that needs a change to access a Silverlight server (I guess you'd call it?)  I've been given a snippet of HTML that I need to post to the server I think.  I don't want to add any new dependencies to my C++ product.  So, how do I post this stuff to the SilverLight web page and get it to show up in a browser, from my C++ app?  (I can use ShellExecute to kick off IE on a local file, or use IWebBrowser, but don't want to add other dependencies.)

Please, if you find this question nonsensical, just don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand silverlight.

Silverlight is a client-side technology (not a server). It communicates to a server in multiple ways.

So here is what you want to do.

1. send stuff from your c++ project to a web server.
2. have server send it to a client (in this case your browser).

How do you do this?

1. Expose a webservice from your server, a wcf service may suffice. Have your c++ application call the expose method and send the data to it.
2. Create a web project that will get the data from the repository (where ever your wcf service saved the data to, a database, file etc.) and display it in html.

You dont need silverlight in this case. It will only come in handy to display.

PS. If you NEED to use silverlight, you need to use COM. Google for 'silverlight COM integration'.

Comment: Shawn, thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I probably didn't explain it well.  A third-party has written something that uses Silverlight.  My old, old C++ app just needs to interface to it.  I've been given some html starting with <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"... with a bunch of <param name="source"... etc.  I have the html all filled out, and I know the server name to go to, and this html snippet has source set to a file ending in".xap".  I think I just need to somehow post this html to that web page.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: could you explain on a conceptual level what you are trying to do?

Comment: There's some Silverlight thing that a 3rd party has created.  It is a mapping application.  We need to pass some parameters to it and "kick it off" in a browser.  They've provided the parameters, I know how to encrypt the ones that need to be encrypted, etc, I have the HTML created, I know the server name (mappingbeta.eac.com.au), I need to somehow feed the HTML to the server, I think.  They don't want the user to have to open it in a browser and login, since we already have their login parameters.

Comment: However… I can't even figure out how to open this thing in a browser!  I'm too dumb to be a Silverlight end-user, apparently.  The .xap file, I found out, is a .zip file, so posting anything to it would appear to be a silly thing to do.  Never mind, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of using submit() in Javascript.  I found an example, plugged the HTML in, and it at least tries to do something.  Says I'm missing a parameter, but I think it's the server's (client's? whatever?) error.